# Retrieve RDS credentials from Secrets Manager in AWS Glue Python Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-glue, aws-secrets-manager

I have a Glue Script which is trying to read the RDS credentials I have stored in Secrets manager. But the Script keeps on running and never completes.
Also, the IAM Role which this Glue Script is running with contains `SecretsManagerReadWrite` policy (AWS Managed)

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrameCollection
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
import boto3
import botocore
from botocore.errorfactory import ClientError
# import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
current_day = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")

def str_to_arr(my_list):
    str = ""
    for item in my_list:
        if item:
            str += item
    str = str.split(" ")
    return '{"' + ' '.join([elem for elem in str])  + '"}'

str_to_arr_udf = udf(str_to_arr,StringType())

def AddPartitionKeys(glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:
    df = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0]).toDF()
    df = glueContext.add_ingestion_time_columns(df, "day")
    glue_df = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "transform_date")
    return(DynamicFrameCollection({"CustomTransform0": glue_df}, glueContext))

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'days', 's3_bucket', 'rds_endpoint', 'region_name', 'secret_name'])

region_name = args['region_name']
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client("secretsmanager", region_name=region_name)
get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=args['secret_name'])
secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
secret = json.loads(secret)
db_username = secret.get('username')
db_password = secret.get('password')
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
print("Below are the creds")
# print("DB USERNAME IS " , db_username)
# print("DB PWD IS " , db_password)
job = Job(glueContext)

job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

job.commit()
```

What am I missing here?

I checked my work against [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-aws-glue-to-run-etl-jobs-against-non-native-jdbc-data-sources/) and yet I am not able to get this script complete successfully.

Comment: If it keeps running and never completes, how do you know it's the SecretsManager portion that is the issue? You should add some logging to determine where the code hangs.

Comment: @MarkB I have done that, right above the line where I am making the API call to SM ```get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=args['secret_name'])``` It never reaches the line past this statement.

Comment: Is your script running in a private VPC subnet without a route to a NAT Gateway?

Comment: To access resources located in another VPC I am adding Glue connections. Are you suggesting that I check the VPC in which the secret is located?

Comment: Secrets aren't "located in VPCs" at all. AWS SecretsManager is a service that exists outside your VPC. That's why I'm asking if the subnet this is running in has access to the Internet, because it either needs Internet access, or AWS service VPC endpoints configured, in order to access these things that are outside the VPC.

Comment: @MarkB I am not sure whether this Glue job is running within a VPC. I can tell the vpc of the connections associated with the job.

Answer (score 1):

After Mark's suggestion, I was able to figure out that I had to create a VPC Interface Endpoint for Secrets Manager. The steps are outlined [here by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoint-overview.html), just had to make sure the policy in the endpoint had access/ARNs mentioned of resources I want to access from Secrets Manager.